# Netbeans compiler in background with Editor API

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-construction

Netbeans IDE compiles my code in background. Can it returns this value? False when is not valit and true when is valid?

I have code with Netbeans Editor API, which can detect when is file modified.

```
try {
        this.doc = ec.openDocument();
        this.file = this.doc.getText(0,this.doc.getLength());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }


     while(true){

         if(ec.isModified()){
             try {

                 if(!this.file.equals( this.doc.getText(0,this.doc.getLength()))){

                     this.file = doc.getText(0,this.doc.getLength());
                     System.out.println("file: " + this.file);


                 }

             } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                 Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
             }

         }
         else
            System.out.println("File without changes");
```

This work fine, but I need detect when is file modified and than detect,that is this file valid or is not valid. Is it posible? I dont need other compiler, but I need Netbeans compiler in background.

Comment: I hope you sleep in the loop... And why do you need this?

Comment: It is loop... this is okay... I am parsing java source code and than I am showing his UML diagram and I need correct java source. This is part when I wrote code in my Editor and UML diagram is automatical upgrade